# how to read .delta files in spark checkpoint

Tags: spark-streaming, delta, checkpoint

In spark checkpoint directory, exists .delta files which record the intermediate status of the streaming.

How can I read the content of it?

When open .delta files as text(utf-8)  by force, it looks like this:

LZ4Block      ۀM    LZ4Block